# How to get current hours in 24 hrs format in Android?

Tags: android, calendar

I am having some trouble using the calendar class in android. How can I get the current time in 24 format?

Comment: This post should help you out. The original poster showed his code for how he was using calendar to get current time and it was returing 24 hour format. His question was about how to get it in 12 hour format, but try what he posted and see if it works. It should work. [Here is the post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976922/problem-with-calendar-getcalendar-hour)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY

Answer (score 12):

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
```

if You want 12 Hour Format Use - `c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, new Date().getHours());`

if You want 24 Hour Format Use - `c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, new Date().getHours());`

Answer (score 10):

Use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` for getting hour in 24 format

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentHour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

You Have To Use This Class > Date Format < You Can Set The Format for Both (Date & Time)

And Here is The Code :

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH/mm/ss");  
Date date = new Date();
dateFormat.format(date);
```

`